# global variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I dont think it is possible but there is no harm to ask.

I have this sql file :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile.csv'
INTO TABLE TCONTACTN4DS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";"
LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n"
```

if there is no path in the INFILE option, it goest to the data/name_of_the_DB folder to get the file.

I could put any path in the infile but let's assume that I dont know the path that will be used and I dont want those scripts to be changed.

Can I declare (dont know where exactly) a global variable that could be changed to describe the path ? How would I use it if it is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mysql documentation on [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) is very explicit about this, so no, you cannot do this:

> The server uses the following rules to locate the file:
>
> - If the file name is an absolute path name, the server uses it as given.
> - If the file name is a relative path name with one or more leading components, the server searches for the file relative to the server's
>     data directory.
> - If a file name with no leading components is given, the server looks for the file in the database directory of the default database.

Since load data cannot be used in stored routines either, you cannot even have a workaround for this limitation.